# Get mongodb warnings in ruby when performing insert/update

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am performing insert/update operation in MongoDB using Ruby. When the insert/update operation fails, I can see the errors in the resulting cursor. But when there is a warning, I don't see it in the resulting cursor. 
I only see this

`#<Mongo::Operation::Insert::Result:0x70353913223340 documents=[{"n"=>1, "ok"=>1.0}]>`

However, checking my mongo logs, I see that a warning was generated when the insert happened

`2019-07-31T17:43:27.959+0530 W STORAGE  [conn429] Document would fail validation collection:`

I want to see this error in Ruby insert operation result.

I have tried setting the Mongo logger level to Debug

`Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG`

But this does not help either.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that but if you have validation warnings on insert then perhaps you should set [`validationAction`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/#accept-or-reject-invalid-documents) to `"error"` (which should be by default unless you changed it)

Comment: If I set validation action to error, the insert fails. I want the insert to go through, but just get in logs that this was not a valid document